# Split text into sentences in C#

Tags: c#, text, split

I want to divide a text into sentences. A sentence ends with (dot) or ? or ! followed by one or more whitespace characters followed and the next sentence starts with an uppercase letter.

For example:

First sentence. Second sentence!

How can I do that?

Comment: How would you handle this: *"When he came to the house, he shouted "Hey! Anybody there?", and then opened the door and went in."* Or you you have very strict control over the input?

Comment: I added a regular expression in my answear that considers this case. Ref http://www.regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=2355

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk Your example is a particularly interesting case. I would handle as a single sentence

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What languages do you want to support? For example, in Thai there are no spaces between words and sentences are separated with space. So, in general, this task is very complex. Also consider the useful comment by Fredrik Mörk.

So, at first you need to define set of rules on what "sentence" is. Then you are welcome to use one of the suggested solutions.

Comment: I want to support mainly English. There are a lot of particular state. for example i have to consider Abbreviations (Dr. Jekyll)

Comment: This should be a comment since there is no answer here, only ask for an update in the question.

Answer (score 34):

You can split on a regular expression that matches white space, with a lookbehind that looks for the sentence terminators:

```
string[] sentences = Regex.Split(input, @"(?<=[\.!\?])\s+");
```

This will split on the white space characters and keep the terminators in the sentences.

Example:

```
string input = "First sentence. Second sentence! Third sentence? Yes.";
string[] sentences = Regex.Split(input, @"(?<=[\.!\?])\s+");

foreach (string sentence in sentences) {
  Console.WriteLine(sentence);
}
```

Output:

```
First sentence.
Second sentence!
Third sentence?
Yes.
```

Note:

This solution only addresses the simple case outlined in the question. To do this for any kind of sentence, or for other languages, the solution would be vastly more complicated. Most likely it's not possible to do something that can handle any sentence, even just in English, considering that the sentence might even be incorrectly written or have misplaced punctuation.

Comment: thank you thank you thank you !!!!!!!!!!!!! thank you thank you thank you ..thanks a ton...needed this badly..was struggling with string.split() function that aloows only single character.

Comment: Be careful because this wouldn't work for things like "Hello Mr. & Mrs. Smith".

Comment: @Yodacheese: Yes, that is true. It would require a vastly more advanced analysis of the meaning of the sentence to catch when a period actually ends a sentence. Consider for example the sentences `"The honorific is Mr. Smith is the surname."`.

Comment: you can add ellipsis: @"(?<=([\.!\?])|(\.{3}))\s+"

Comment: This is a really bad solution

Comment: @AX: Why do you think so?

Comment: Why close this question? I think admin need to intervein! Admin need to fix a lot of stuff on this site!

Comment: @RustyNail: Well, admins can only do so much, and this question is a bit of a mess. The currently accepted answer is not even an answer to the question. Perhaps the community can do something to clear up the question so that it can be reopened? I added a note to my answer outlining the limitations with the solutions and the possible problems with the question.

Answer (score 4):

Try this ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/b873y76a.aspx))

```
char[] separators = new char[] {'!', '.', '?'};
string[] sentences1 = "First sentence. Second sentence!".Split(separators);
//or...
string[] sentences2 = "First sentence. Second sentence!".Split('!', '.', '?');
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `String.Split()`? See the docs about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)

Comment: yes i did, but it is not sufficient. In text there are links. (Ex: www.mysite.it)