# Improve regex to Split large text into sentences

Tags: c#, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a regular expression for parsing out individual sentences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936388/what-is-a-regular-expression-for-parsing-out-individual-sentences)

I want to split large text into sentence . The regex expression i got from answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957226/split-text-into-sentences-in-c-sharp)

```
string[] sentences = Regex.Split(mytext, @"(?<=[\.!\?])\s+");
```

So I thought of using a pattern to do splitting like 
if a `.` `?` `!` follows a `space` and a **`capital`** letter than do the split. 
Capital letter indicates starting of sentence .

```
text = " Sentence one . Sentence e.g. two ? Sentence three.
sentence[1] = Sentence one 
sentence[2] = Sentence e.g. two
```

For problematic cases like abbreviations i intend to do replacing

```
mytext.replace("e.g.","eg");
```

How to implement this in regex ?

Comment: Look at this [question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936388/what-is-a-regular-expression-for-parsing-out-individual-sentences). I'd really veer toward a NLP parser than doing regular expressions.

Comment: Have you tried adding `[A-Z]` like this : `(?<=[\.!\?])\s[A-Z]+` ?

Comment: If a capital letter starts a sentence (in your use case..).. why not split by them using normal split functions?

Comment: I have been asked to implemnt this functionality in already heavy asp.net application . NLP would slow things down and since its totally new for me , it will take some time. For moment I want to implemnt with reasonable accuracy. There is manual Quality testing afterwards which removes errorenous capturing of sentence

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\p{Lt}` indicates a Unicode uppercase letter (including accents etc.), so

```
string[] sentences = Regex.Split(mytext, @"(?<=[.!?])\s+(?=\p{Lt})");
```

should do what you want.

(Note that I don't think `.` or `?` need to be escaped in a character class so I've removed them too, but do check that this still works with those characters.)

However, note that this will still split on e.g. `Mr. Jones`...

Comment: @"(?<=[.!?])\s+(?=[A-Z])" works correctly . thanks

Comment: It's not working for `My name is Dr. X. Also not working for Mr. X and Mrs. Y. `