# How to find longest sentence in text?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have text file similar to this:

> C#[note 2] (pronounced as see sharp) is a multi-paradigm programming
>   language encompassing strong typing, imperative, declarative,
>   functional, generic, object-oriented (class-based), and
>   component-oriented programming disciplines. It was developed by
>   Microsoft within its .NET initiative and later approved as a standard
>   by Ecma (ECMA-334) and ISO (ISO/IEC 23270:2006). C# is one of the
>   programming languages designed for the Common Language Infrastructure.
>   C# is intended to be a simple, modern, general-purpose,
>   object-oriented programming language.[7] Its development team is led
>   by Anders Hejlsberg. The most recent version is C# 6.0, which was
>   released on July 20, 2015.[8]

How can I find longest sentence in this text? Should I read it using `string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);`?

Edit: You say is impossible. But this was a task i was given by a teacher..

Okay, how to do this with this text file?:

> Text messaging, or  texting, is the act of composing and sending
>   brief, electronic messages between two or more mobile phones,  or
>   fixed or portable devices over a phone network. The term originally
>   referred to messages sent using the Short Message Service (SMS). It
>   has grown to include messages containing image, video, and sound
>   content (known as MMS messages). The sender of a text message is known
>   as a texter, while the service itself has different colloquialisms
>   depending on the region. It may simply be referred to as a text in
>   North America, the United Kingdom, Australia, New Zealand and  the
>   Philippines, an SMS in most of mainland Europe, and an MMS or SMS in
>   the Middle East, Africa, and Asia.

Comment: Please define "sentence"

Comment: First you need to define "sentence". Then you need to write code to parse arbitrary string input into one or more sentences. Then you can simply sort these by length. Please read [ask] and share your research.

Comment: Basically "impossible". You can split on `. ` (including a space) to fix the `.NET` bug (where it'll split those into 2). You can then check which item in the array has the biggest length.

Comment: As the method says ReadAllLines reads the lines as they are written in the file. So you will not get the exact sentences. To accomplish what you want you will have to look in to some heavy regular expressions. with that you can sort the text into sentences. But it will be difficult because you have to take into account that a sentence doesn't just end at a '.' as you can see at '.NET'. You will then have to look for pieces where there is a space after a dot and so on.

Comment: Programmatically determining what constitutes the sentences in a paragraph is quite a complex task. You will have to handle edge cases like `.NET` and if you split on `. ` (a dot followed by a space), you would not split your last sentence correctly, if it was followed by another sentence as it end with `2015.[8]` and lacks the space after the `.`.

Comment: @noob156: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4957295/395500 here is some good answer to it.

Comment: @NirajDoshi how do i read file? The problem is, text file doesn't contains only one line :(

Comment: @noob156: You may check the edited answer.

Comment: As for your edit: nobody is saying it is impossible. It is just not trivial, and you need to show what you have tried. We're not here to do your homework. You can perhaps make a simple implementation work on the second example text, but that same code will fail for the first text, and I'm sure your teacher will have more creative input for your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to split English text by sentences (and not just for a homework exercise), I would recommend the use of one of the open source natural language processing tools, for example [SharpNLP](http://sharpnlp.codeplex.com/) which is a C# port of the Java OpenNLP tools. I have downloaded the source code for this from [GitHub](https://github.com/AlexPoint/OpenNlp) and created the following example in its `Test` project. This program outputs 6 sentences and the longest sentence is actually the first sentence.

```
using OpenNLP.Tools.SentenceDetect;

namespace Test
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static readonly string currentDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/../../";

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var inputText =
                "C#[note 2] (pronounced as see sharp) is a multi-paradigm programming language encompassing strong typing, imperative, declarative, functional, generic, object-oriented (class-based), and component-oriented programming disciplines. It was developed by Microsoft within its .NET initiative and later approved as a standard by Ecma (ECMA-334) and ISO (ISO/IEC 23270:2006). C# is one of the programming languages designed for the Common Language Infrastructure. C# is intended to be a simple, modern, general-purpose, object-oriented programming language.[7] Its development team is led by Anders Hejlsberg. The most recent version is C# 6.0, which was released on July 20, 2015.[8]";
            var sentenceDetector =
                new EnglishMaximumEntropySentenceDetector(currentDirectory + "../Resources/Models/EnglishSD.nbin");
            string[] sentences = sentenceDetector.SentenceDetect(inputText);


            string longest = sentences.OrderByDescending(s => s.Length).First();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the proper answer. You don't want to reinvent the wheel for nontrivial tasks, you leverage the work that others have done through the code or libraries they offer. If you can motivate that properly, the teacher will have to accept that. If the exercise is to learn about the `string.Split()` method, then unfortunately that is the "correct" answer that the teacher expects, but it is not the correct answer in any other sense.

Answer (score -2):

**Edit:** After you have edited your question. I will take [Guffa's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4957295/395500) answer to split strings and take longest of it.

```
    string lines;

    try
    {   // Open the text file using a stream reader.
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt"))
           lines = sr.ReadToEnd();     
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }

    List<string> sentences = Regex.Split("", @"(?<=[\.!\?])\s+").ToList();
    var longestSentences = sentences.Where(s => s.Length == sentences.Max(l => l.Length));
    List<int> indexsOfLongestSentences = new List<int>();

    if(longestSentences.Any())
            indexsOfLongestSentences.AddRange(longestSentences.Select(longestSentence => sentences.IndexOf(longestSentence)));
```

---

**Answer before question was edited**

This is an incorrect way:

```
string[] lines = fileText.Split('.');
var line =lines.Max(l=>l.Length);
```

Comment: A line does not necessarily equal a sentence. This will also incorrectly split `C# 6.0` as two sentences.

Comment: But a sentence ends with a period.

Comment: Not if it is a question or exclamation.

Comment: Hmmm, yes right. More string split options needed !

Comment: But also with ? or !. Also, you have to take into consideration the '.NET' word for example.

Comment: @Joshua no, you cannot define a sentence as "ending with a period" for various reasons. `string.Split()` is not going to help here if you want to do it properly.

Comment: A sentence ends with `.`, `?` or `!` followed by at least one whitespace or end of string or `[`... right?

Comment: @Laura Another good example. Although having negative points, I will leave it here to let someone (like me) know that this is bad  (incorrect) way.

Comment: Sorry for another stupid question, but longestSentence is an integer, right? How to print the longest sentence?

Comment: @noob156 What do you mean by an integer, do you mean `Sentence Number` or `Length of words in a sentence` ? Check the edit if you meant `Sentence Number`.

Comment: @NirajDoshi Thank you, I needed this too. But variable longestSentence is a string or integer?

Comment: @noob156: Its a `string`. But you can use `var` when you initialize an object and let compiler infer the type for you.

Comment: @NirajDoshi, my Visual Studio 2012 says it is a integer. Why?

Comment: @noob156: your compiler is correct. Sorry I didn't notice that. I have edited the answer. I have also considered the fact that there can be more than one longest sentence in the paragraph. So you may end-up getting two or more longest sentences with same length.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `string.Split(new string[]{"."},StringSplitOptions.None)` method to 
splt string to array of sentences
and then you can choose longest with string.Length

Comment: No, you can't split on dot. The example text already contains `C# 6.0`, which will cause a false match.

Comment: why I can`t split on dot

Comment: Because there can be dots in a text that do not denote the end of a sentence, and not all sentences have to end in a dot.

Comment: Yes,it is right,But if really he needs to split by sentences he needs to use dot

Answer (score -3):

There is no way. Sorry, but when your text includes stuff like `"within its .NET initiative and later approved"`, and `"sion is C# 6.0, which "`, There's really no *reliable* way to determine where an actual sentence begins and when one ends.

Comment: There is always a way. But not always a simple one as in this case.

Comment: You can split on `. ` except of `.` to fix that. There's almost always a way. The only question for me is why you would do it.

Comment: that doesnt work in the case of `"object-oriented programming language.[7] Its "`

Comment: The paragraph OP provided is a good example of why you cannot *reliably* determine sentences programatically

Comment: You guys can mark this answer down all you want but i still stand behind it 100%

Comment: There can be reliable ways to split a sentence, if it is defined and processed correctly. You are misusing the term `reliable`, instead it should be  `No one way` to achieve it.