# What regular expression in Regex Split can split text into sentences where sentence start in new line of textbox and not right after a period mark?

Tags: c#, regex

Here is the code:

```
string StringFromTheInput = TextBox1.Text; string[] splichar1 =
Regex.Split(StringFromTheInput, @"(?<=[.])\n\r+");
```

The input:

```
First sentence. Second sentence. Third sentence.
```

I want this output:

```
First sentence.  
Second sentence.  
Third sentence.
```

So the main point is to put every splitted text with period mark into new line of textbox and not a continuous text. The code only splits the texts but does not put the sentences in new line.

Comment: Either use `Regex.Replace()` instead of `Regex.Split()` or use `string.Join()` to join the sentences after splitting them. That being said, if you're only looking for periods, specifically, it doesn't really look like you need Regex for this. Something like `TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(".", "." + Environment.NewLine);` would do the job.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957226/split-text-into-sentences-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

If you're only looking for periods, specifically, it doesn't really look like you need Regex. You could just write something like:

```
TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(". ", "." + Environment.NewLine);
```

If you need to support other punctuation marks or you want to use Regex for some other reason, you could either use `Regex.Replace()`:

```
TextBox1.Text = Regex.Replace(TextBox1.Text, @"[.?!] ", "$&\r\n");
```

Or use `Regex.Split()` and then re-join the sentences:

```
var sentences = Regex.Split(TextBox1.Text, @"(?<=[.?!]) ");
TextBox1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, sentences);
// Or...
//TextBox1.Lines = sentences;
```

Comment: yes this - TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(". ", "." + Environment.NewLine); works fine

Comment: @user20465780 All three options should work fine. It comes down to what your actual requirements are. If you want to support question marks and exclamation points, go with the second or third option. If you only care about periods, the first option is the most straightforward for that particular use case.

Comment: I need one little help please.   How to split a text by words Instead of .?! marks? I

Comment: It depends on what you consider a word. You could split on a space character, but that would include special characters as part of the words. If you only want to extract actual words (e.g., alphanumeric), you could use `Regex.Match(input, @"\w+")` but that would ignore any special characters in the string. If your question is different, you may post a new question **after doing sufficient research** to make sure your question isn't a duplicate.

Comment: something like this: sentences = Regex.Split(TextBox1.Text, @"(?<=[\because\now]) ");  can text be splitted by words??      Text: I feel good because sunshine.        Output: because sunshine.    Othere example-> Text:  I like it because it is light but I dont lilke it because it is expensive, OutPut: because it is light but I do not like it because